# PHP Fatal error:Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, undefined

I've followed a tutorial to add a MySQL database into my PHP website. I've been following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPspjWX8GXw

I'm using PHP Version 5.5.33 and XAMPP. 
I've even replaced all of my code with his working code and it still didn't work.

The exact error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\assign\Model\FoodModel.php on line 33

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are using 5.5.33? Might as well just update to `PDO` or `mysqli` anyway. Also not a good tutorial. Tutorials shouldn't have SQL injections written into them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mysqli` extension instead of `mysql`. Please make sure you don't use very old tutorials with the `mysql` extension, it's outdated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion . I'm new to PHP and I'm doing my absolute best to learn from different tutorials. I've replaced mysql with mysqli , however I still have problems.

Ex:Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given